# Cordova hide app for background

Tags: cordova-plugins

How to hide the application for background by closing it in ios and android?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly it is you want to do?

Comment: I want the application to be hidden when people click on home button (but be connected), only disconnects when the desconnect button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem.

I used this plugin:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

executing this command ( `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.excludeFromTaskList()`; ) the APP becomes invisible (not appearing to the user) running in the background.

and coming back to be visible:

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.moveToForeground();
```